# Function call not calling synchronously REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to create a HTML list with the below code. I have managed to create it. but for some reason the output is not in order.

Is the function calls synchronously? when i put alert(heading); in Link() it shows the correct output.

```
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MyFunction");

    function MyFunction() 
    {

            $.ajax({

                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mega Menu')/items?$select=Title,Main_x0020_Heading",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var uniqueNames = groupByHeading(data, 'Main_x0020_Heading');
                    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {

                    }    
                    subheading("INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY");
                },
                error: function(error){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }    
            });
    }

    function subheading(heading) {
        // alert(heading);
        $.ajax({

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mega Menu')/items?$select=Sub_x0020_Heading&$filter=(Main_x0020_Heading eq '" + encodeURIComponent(heading) + "')&$orderby=Sub_x0020_Heading_x0020_Order",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var uniqueNames = groupBySubHeading(data, 'Sub_x0020_Heading');
                $('#divListItems').append('<ul>'+heading+'</ul>');
                for (var i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {
                    $('#divListItems').append("<li>" + uniqueNames[i] + "</li>");
                    links(uniqueNames[i]);
                } 
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }

    function links(heading) {

        $.ajax({

            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mega Menu')/items?$select=Links&$filter=(Sub_x0020_Heading eq '" + encodeURIComponent(heading) + "')&$orderby=link_x0020_order",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var uniqueNames = groupByLink(data, 'Links');
                $('#divListItems').append('<ul>' + heading + '</ul>');
                for (var i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {
                    $('#divListItems').append("<li>" + uniqueNames[i] + "</li>");
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });
    }
    function groupByHeading(items, propertyName) {
        var result = [];

        var allValues = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each(items.d.results, function (index, item) {
            allValues[i] = item.Main_x0020_Heading;
            i++;

        });

        $.each(allValues, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, result) === -1) result.push(el);
        });
        return result;
    }

    function groupBySubHeading(items, propertyName) {
        var result = [];

        var allValues = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each(items.d.results, function (index, item) {
            allValues[i] = item.Sub_x0020_Heading;
            i++;

        });

        $.each(allValues, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, result) === -1) result.push(el);
        });
        return result;
    }

    function groupByLink(items, propertyName) {
        var result = [];

        var allValues = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each(items.d.results, function (index, item) {
            allValues[i] = item.Links;
            i++;

        });

        $.each(allValues, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, result) === -1) result.push(el);
        });
        return result;
    }
</script>
```

If i comment out links(uniqueNames[i]); i will get the  part correctly,
[image]

But otherwise

[image]